# Ember View does not updating as of the change that happen to the model immediately

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

When I am making an AJAX request to update some values the data or model is changing. But the updated model is not reflecting immediately. It is reflecting only after clicking refresh. I want to only modify a view of a div in the page. I have tried many things but not successful. Can anyone suggest me the way to solve the issue?
The git repo: 
https://github.com/SyamPhanindraChavva/trell-app-front-end

**templates/note.hbs**

```
 <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <p><a class="dropdown-item" {{action 'updateNote' "doing" note.id}}>DOING</a></p>
    <p><a class="dropdown-item"{{action 'updateNote' "done" note.id}}>DONE</a></p>
    <p><a class="dropdown-item"{{action 'deleteNote'  note.id}}>DELETE</a></p>
  </div>
```

**controllers/notes.js**

```
status2:Ember.inject.service('work-status'),
actions: {
    updateNote(upstatus,id){
        let status1 = Ember.get(this,'status2');
        status1.makeputrequest(upstatus,id);
        this.toggleProperty('parameter');
    }
}
```

**services/work-status.js**

```
makeputrequest(status1,id1)
  {
    $.when($.ajax ({
  //  get(this,'layout.referrer.owner.router').transitionTo('notes');
        type: 'PUT',
        url:'http://localhost:3000/notes/'+id1,
        data: {note:{status:status1}},

      })).then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
      }).catch(function(err){
        console.log("you have error")
      });
},
```

The thing I am trying to make is whenever I change the status of a record  the corresponding record in the UI must also go to the corresponding table or container in UI.

Comment: I've updated your comment with the relevant snippets of code that were causing the issue.  In the future, please make sure to include a reduced, reproducible problem, rather than a link to your entire repo. Take a look at "[how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)", it'll help you get more help in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using ajax calls directly in ember, you'll be responsible for setting the new properties once it's complete.

In services/work-status.js, you'll want to return the promises generated by the ajax calls.

In controllers/notes.js,  chain .then to the returned promise and call and set the new property.

**EG - controllers/notes.js**

```
updateNote(upstatus,id){
    let status1 = Ember.get(this,'status2');
    status1.makeputrequest(upstatus,id).then((){
        this.get('model').findBy('id',id).set('status',upstatus);
    });
},
```

---

With that said, this isn't the correct route to take.  You're mixing ember-data with plain ajax calls which is making the logic of your codebase more difficult than necessary.

If you modify your action to take the entire note as an argument,  change the status, and just save the model, you wouldn't need to use the service.

```
// templates/note.hbs
<p><a class="dropdown-item" {{action 'updateNote' note "doing"}}>DOING</a></p>

// controllers/note.js
updateNote(note,upstatus) {
    note.set('status',upstatus)
    note.save();
}
```

Comment: Its not working it is throwing  this error when we try to save. error image link: 
 https://i.imgur.com/nbyXtpN.png

Comment: And at the same time. My issue is the UI part must change when updating the model. The UI for my code is updating after refresh. I want that to be updated after changing the status. My ui image: https://i.imgur.com/QC7i29I.png . After changing status the record from todo must move to done area in display like dynamic ui change based on model data.

Comment: There is a small bug in this nice answer. `set()` returns the value passed in not a reference to the object. Therefore it throws if calling `save()` on `upstatus`. So this should be: `note.set('status',upstatus); note.save();`

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is only meant if you are not trying to change something on the records. However, if you would like to change a value of your records you should be using `ember-data`